# Converting string to date not working

Tags: python, datetime

I just can't seem to get this to work - I'm pretty sure I've for the syntax for `strptime()` correct but its not working. The output expected is `31 Aug 2015`:

```
str = '31 Aug 2015 at 23:59'

try:
    mydate = datetime.strptime(str, '%d %b %Y')
    print mydate
except ValueError:
    mydate = None
    print "error"
```

I get "error" printed out. What am I missing?

The `str` variable is read from a file so it could have any data in it. I'm just looking for entries that have a valid date (Day Month Year) present.

Comment: Don't use `str` as a variable name as it is a builtin

Comment: Doesnt work if I use mystring instead of str.

Comment: You are throwing out the information about what is causing the exception. Remove the try block and look at the error. It says: `ValueError: unconverted data remains:  at 23:59`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to take into account the `at 23:59` part too:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>>
>>> s = '31 Aug 2015 at 23:59'
>>> datetime.strptime(s, "%d %b %Y at %H:%M")
datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 31, 23, 59)
```

Or, alternatively, let [`dateutil`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-dateutil) do the job:

```
>>> from dateutil.parser import parse
>>> 
>>> s = '31 Aug 2015 at 23:59'
>>> parse(s)
datetime.datetime(2015, 8, 31, 23, 59)
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks very much. I was not aware you needed to do that.